# Can I change the Authentication Flow of Firebase Auth UI?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

According to the [Firebase documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md#response-codes):  If a user enters a non-existing email address, the flow takes the user to the sign-up part. In my app there will be no signing-up section. How can I skip sign-up part and redirect user to the sign in screen?

here is the code:

```
 // Choose authentication providers
    List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build());

    // Create and launch sign-in intent
    startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                    .build(),
            RC_SIGN_IN);
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // RC_SIGN_IN is the request code you passed into startActivityForResult(...) when starting the sign in flow.
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);

        // Successfully signed in
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //startActivity(SignedInActivity.createIntent(this, response));
            finish();
        }
        else {

            // Sign in failed
            if (response == null) {


            }

            if (response.getError().getErrorCode() == ErrorCodes.NO_NETWORK) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No Connection." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: FirebaseUI is just a convenience method for people who aren't doing anything special in their sign-in flow. If you need something custom, it would probably be better to build it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible: use `setAllowNewAccounts`. (Looks like we forgot to add docs, sorry about that.)

Full example:

```
new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder()
    .setAllowNewAccounts(false)
    .build()
```

Comment: Where can i see the other methods like this one? For example, I don't want firebase to ask the user "having problem signing-in?" or can i edit the texts?

Comment: That can't be changed unfortunately. Methods to modify providers are available on each individual provider builder.

Comment: Found a stupid way. First, copy the related layout and edit the button's width and height as 0. Second,Make button's string name empty. Stupid but it will work.

Comment: Yeah, just be careful when you upgrade FUI versions since that's not public API and anything can change without notice.